# Webpack bundles CSS in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

At the moment, my webpack is bundling my CSS styles like this:

```
//this css is going first, it's supposed to go last
.rbc-btn {
  color: red;
}
//this css must be first
.myStyle {
  color: green;
}
```

What I want is to bundle my CSS styles in a specific order, something like this:

```
.myStyle {
  color: green;
}
.rbc-btn {
  color: red;
}
```

How can I fix this with webpack?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

There was a similar bug that was fixed with `extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.0`, ensure you're using the same version or newer.

If that doesn't help, a common mistake is to load a component first and then loading the CSS files. It has become a common pattern to make every component to import their own styles which can change the style order in webpack if your component is loaded first.

Considering you have `index.js` like this:

```
import MyApp from './myApp'
import './myStyle.css'
```

It means to Webpack that every style imported in './myApp' will be loaded first, so styles applied 'myStyle.css' will appear below other styles, thus overriding them.

The fix could potentially be just changing orders

```
import './myStyle.css' // parent component imports style first
import MyApp from './myApp' // imports your component along with any other styles
```

Comment: I'm using webpack 4, which is not recomended with `extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.0`. Any solution for webpack v4?

Comment: you can use mini-css-extract-plugin for webpack 4.has a test case for the bug you're facing https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/commit/97e2f4cb3114e89cdccdcb57b0b88eca20dd11d9. also ensure your styles are loaded properly as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Cezar Augusto's answer:

If you have module.css, the import order of the components whose module.css is being bundled together will impact the order!

So for me I needed @import for fonts in my css to be bundled on top first, so in my index.js file, I needed to import my module.css file with my @import first before importing my components whose module.css needed to be bundled later.